# Change current li class (the one who is clicked)

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, class, dom

I have many li(list) items which are generated by a loop thanks to java servlets, now
I want to change the class of the current li(list) which is selected

```
      $('li.doBlokkeer').click(function(e) {
    $('.doBlokkeer').addClass('doDEBlokkeer').removeClass('doBlokkeer');
      });
```

so if a current li is selected its class need to be changed (it needs to have doDEBlokkeer).
The above code works.. but it changes ALL my li items... so guys do you know how to change the class of the current item $(this) ? I have no jquery skill, pls help me out. Thanks!!

Comment: `$(this).addClass(....`

Comment: Note that removing the class does not remove the event handler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `$(this)` instead of `$('.doBlokkeer')` in the click event handler. As `$('.doBlokkeer')` will return all the elements having class `doBlokkeer` where as `$(this)` represents the jQuery object that is source of the event.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ajvS2/)**

```
$('li.doBlokkeer').click(function(e) {
   $(this).addClass('doDEBlokkeer').removeClass('doBlokkeer');
});
```

You can also try using [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to switch between two classes.

**[Live Demmo](http://jsfiddle.net/ajvS2/1/)**

```
$('li.doBlokkeer').click(function(e) {        
   $(this).toggleClass('doDEBlokkeer');
});
```

Comment: I thought this was the solution, but it doesnt seem to work.. nothing happens with your code. If i change 'this' into 'doBlokkeer', all my LI items change.. but I need the current(this) to be changed. Any other solution?
What can be the reason?

Comment: Can you show us the html?, check this demo, http://jsfiddle.net/ajvS2/ and my updated ander

Comment: Adil, the first answer was correct. I messed up because I had a <a href> in my LI class with the same class name. this caused issues. I remove the a href class and placed it all in the list class. 

Now it works perfectly! thank you

Comment: Actually this works only once, when I click on li.doBlokkeer the class changes which is good, but when I press the same current li again, it calls the same function li.doBlokkeer  instead of li.doDEBlokkeer function (despite the css class) . I tried so much stuff but i really can't find any solution. can you guys help me out?

Comment: Please check the second solution given in my answer using toggleClass, http://jsfiddle.net/ajvS2/1/